# Python3: command not found, when running from cli

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to run my python module as a command, however I am always getting the error: `command not found`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re
from sys import stdin
from sys import stdout

class Grepper(object):
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        self.pattern = pattern

    def pgreper(self):
        y = (str(self.pattern))
        for line in sys.stdin:
            regex = re.compile(y)
            x = re.search(regex, line)
            if x:
                sys.stdout.write(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("hello")
    pattern = str(sys.argv[1])
    Grepper(pattern).pgreper()
else:
    print("nope")
```

I am sure whether it has something to do with the line:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

However I  just can't figure it out, this is a new area for me, and it's a bit stressful.

Comment: what happens if you run `python` in the command line?

Comment: It would help if you showed exactly what you are typing to run this "as a command".

Comment: try "python test.py hello" works for me.

Comment: How are you running it, exactly? Your `if __name__ == "__main__":` line is ok, but I suspect that the `else:` part doesn't do what you think it does: it will print `nope` if you import your module.

Comment: Hi Guys:

When I run python in the command line, I get the python2.7 interpreter

I run the command like this "cat input.txt | pgreper "string"

Comment: Can we assume that this script is in the current directory of your terminal?

Comment: Yes it is in my current directory :)

Comment: Why have you still not shown how you are actually running this script?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have shown how I run my script, this is what I run on the command line:

cat input.txt | pgreper "String" > output.txt

The idea is to create a python version of grep

Comment: If it's in your working directory, you have to run it as `./pgreper.py`. If you want to run it as `pgreper`, you have to make a symlink (named `pgreper`) in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Hi there, yes I seen your comment, sorry I am only getting back to it now. As part of this assignment I do not think that I am allowed to edit /usr/bin :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script name should have a `.py` extension, so it should be named something like `pgreper.py`.

To run it, you need to do either `python pgreper.py pattern_string` or if it has executable permission, as explained by Gabriel, you can do `./pgreper.py pattern_string`. Note that you **must** give the script path (unless the current directory is in your command PATH); `pgreper.py pattern_string` will cause bash to print the "command not found" error message.

<s>You **can't** pass the pattern data to it by piping, IOW, `cat input.txt | ./pgreper.py "pattern_string"` won't work: the pattern has to be passed as an argument on the command line. I guess you *could* do `./pgreper.py "$(cat input.txt)"` but it'd be better to modify the script to read from stdin if you need that functionality.</s>

Sorry, I didn't read the body of your script properly. :embarrassed:
I now see that your `pgreper()` method reads data from stdin. Sorry if the paragraph above caused any confusion.

---

By way of apology for my previous gaffe, here's a slightly cleaner version of your script.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

class Grepper(object):
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        self.pattern = pattern

    def pgreper(self):
        regex = re.compile(self.pattern)
        for line in sys.stdin:
            if regex.search(line):
                sys.stdout.write(line)


def main():
    print("hello")
    pattern = sys.argv[1]
    Grepper(pattern).pgreper()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
else:
    print("nope")
```

Comment: Hi,

I see your point.  The file does exist with a .py extension, eg pgreper.py.

I can currently run the program, and get the correct output by typing this in the command line:  cat input.txt | python3 pgreper.py "string" > out.txt

My aim is to be able to run the program as cat input.txt | pgreper "string" > out.txt.  The same way you would run grep :)

Comment: ps Don't worry no confusion caused :)

Comment: @jeff_h: I already addressed that in my comment. Quote: If you want to run it as `pgreper`, you have to make a symlink (named `pgreper`) in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: In that case, you either need to add the directory containing the script to your system command path (the list of directories that gets printed when you do `echo $PATH`), or link the script to a directory in that path list. You _could_ use `/usr/bin` as Rawing suggests; I prefer to put my personal stuff in `~/bin`, i.e a `bin/` folder in my home directory which I've added to my PATH by editing `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @Rawing Hi there, yes I seen your comment, sorry I am only getting back to it now.  As part of this assignment I do not think that I am allowed to edit /usr/bin :(

Comment: @jeff_h: `.py` extension is not necessary (correct shebang and executable permissions are all you need). It is even harmful. Imagine, you've decided to rewrite it in another language one day (e.g., I know but I don't care what language `/usr/bin/xrotate` uses on my system). To be fair, I usually use `*.py` files for development. And install them as scripts (e.g., by creating a symlink somewhere in PATH)  without any file extension.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Sure, the `.py` extension is not necessary when running the script as a program. But it is necessary (AFAIK) if you want to import it as a module. And since the start of the question refers to it as a module, I felt it was appropriate to make sure that the extension was present.

Comment: @PM2Ring: the question is **not** about *importing* a module. `.py` extension should not be the first thing in your answer.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yeah, ok.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have something executable here : `/usr/bin/env`.

When you try to run your python module as a command, it will call this as an interpreter. You may need to replace it with `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python3` if you don't have an `env` command.

Also, make sure your file is executable : `chmod +x my_module.py` and try to run it with `./my_module.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Changed my first line to: #!/usr/bin/python3

Permissions for my script are -rwxrwxrwx.

However I am still getting the same command not found error.  When I run my script like this: cat input.txt | pgreper "string" >> output.txt

Comment: Try `which python` or `which python3` to know what your sha-bang (first line beginning by `#!`) should be.

Comment: Which python3, returns:

/usr/bin/python3